# How to list pods and nodes using AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I have a cluster in AWS EKS and 1 node group which has 1 node, how to display node and pods using aws api? I have credentials for service account, how to use these credentials in an API and get list of available nodes and pods?
when I try to execute command `kubectl get pods` it shows an error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: >arn:aws:iam:xxxx:user/xx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: >arn:aws:iam::xx:user/xx

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things before accessing your cluster.

1. Add your IAM Roles or Users to the [aws-auth ConfigMap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) to configure who can access the cluster. The IAM role that was used for creating the cluster, already have access.
2. When accessing the cluster, you must authenticate and populate your `kubeconfig`. This can be done with [aws eks update-kubeconfig command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html#examples):

   `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <my-cluster-name>`